# Metavariables in code markdown

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting

Often when providing code snippets in answers, you want to mark some parts of the code as placeholder metavariables; this is commonly rendered in italics. For instance, in my answer to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028497/return-from-a-nested-loop-in-common-lisp) I'd like that `function-name` in the code be a metavariable. Is there any way to do this? If not, please convert this to a feature request.

Comment: There isn't. Converted.

Comment: Note that this is not likely to happen - markdown is a specification and SO implements it in the editor (with some small extensions). This is not a _small_ extension.